# Dialogflow v2 api fails on authentication in Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es

So my code works on console but if I try to import the module or run the code on the web I get `google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded` error.

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversaion."""
    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('=' * 20)
        print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
        print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))


print (detect_intent_texts('newagent-38239', '12121211', ['Hi there'], 'en-US'))
```

I have the authentication setup and env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` setup. Like I said earlier the code works on the console or if I try to run the program like `python main.py`. If I try to import the module or run it on the web server it fails:

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: Well, I get serviceunavailable Error which is not addressed in that doc: `ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded `

Comment: @DaImTo, any thoughts, mate?